# Confused about NSTableView Identifier on Table Cell View

Tags: macos, swift3, nstableview

I am able to create simple view based NSTableViews but there's one point I don't understand about identifiers.

In an NSTableView you typically give a column an identifier and then implement the delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
```

And then you switch on the column to do what you need, something like:

```
switch tableColumn!.identifier {
case "firstColumn":
    //do something...
case "secondColumn":
    //do something else...
default:
    return nil
}
```

However additionally you can give each **Table Cell View an identifier as well.** So in the above example, say I didn't give the identifier to the column, and instead gave the identifier to the **Table Cell View itself**.

I presumed that then I could do something like this in the delegate method:

```
if let firstColumnCellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "firstColumnCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
    view.textField?.stringValue = "Hi! I'm in the first column"
    return view
} else if let secondColumnCellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "secondColumnCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
    view.textField?.stringValue = "Hi! I'm in the second column"
    return view
} else {
    return nil
}
```

This works, but never makes it past the first `if let` statement, and so all my cells say "Hi! I'm in the first column"

---

More Info:

Something else I don't understand: it seems that the **Table Cell View identifier overrides the identifier to the column.**

If I go to the document outline and assign identifiers something like this:

```
tableColumn: "firstColumn"
    tableViewCell: "firstColumnCell"

tableColumn: "secondColumn"
    tableViewCell: "secondColumnCell"
```

and then **supply both the column identifier and the cell identifier**, it works!

```
 switch tableColumn!.identifier {
    case "firstColumn":
        if let firstColumnCellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "firstColumnCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
            view.textField?.stringValue = "Hi! I'm in the first column"
            return view
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    case "secondColumn":
        if let secondColumnCellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "secondColumnCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
            view.textField?.stringValue = "Hi! I'm in the second column"
            return view
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    default:
        return nil
    }
```

But it **crashes if I allow the switch statement to ignore the cell identifier for the second column**, and fall through to trying to use the column identifier.

```
 switch tableColumn!.identifier {
    case "firstColumn":
        if let firstColumnCellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "firstColumnCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
            view.textField?.stringValue = "Hi! I'm in the first column"
            return view
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    default:
        break
    }


    let cellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    cellView.textField?.stringValue = "hello"
    return cellView

    //CRASH: Unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping tableColumn!.identifier
    // The column both exists and has an identifier of "secondColumn", so how could
    //this be nil?
```

And it seems I can confirm this overriding behavior by **renaming the secondColumnCell to the same name as the secondColumn**:

```
tableColumn: "firstColumn"
    tableViewCell: "firstColumnCell"

tableColumn: "secondColumn" <--- Same Name
    tableViewCell: "secondColumn" <-- Same Name
```

And now the code runs as expected and doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your last chunk of code correctly, you instantiate (or retrieve from a *used-views-no-longer-on-screen* pool - see [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableview/1535482-make)) a view with the identifier **firstColumnCell**.

As long as the identifier is valid (you have somewhere a nib defining the view) the method will always return a non-nil view so the first `if let ...` will always succeed.

So the `view.textField?.stringValue =  "Hi! I'm in the first column"` will execute thus showing the message in the cell and then it will return the view to be used by the NSTableView and exit your method.

The next `if let ...` statements will never have a chance to execute.

Comment: ThanksI added more info to the question. Sorry I'm still not understanding.